# phonegap android register for gcm

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phonegap and trying to develop an application for android to get it registered with GCM. i have set up the project in google API's. am following the steps in the PushPlugin. i have managed top get the code to run, though i am unable to get the registration id of the device. i am testing on an emulator.

My index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>com.PhoneGap.c2dm</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

                document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                    if( $("#home").length > 0)
                    {
                        // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                        //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        navigator.app.backHistory();
                    }
                }, false);

                try 
                { 
                    console.log("Inside Try-Catch");
                    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"registration_id","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});      // required!
                    } else {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
                }
                catch(err) 
                { 
                    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                    txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                    alert(txt); 
                } 
            }

            // handle APNS notifications for iOS
            function onNotificationAPN(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }

                if (e.sound) {
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }

                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            }

            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotificationGCM(e) {
                console.log("Inside onOnNotificationGCM");
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                        if (e.foreground)
                        {
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                            // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                            my_media.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                            if (e.coldstart)
                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                            else
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        }

                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

         </script>
        <div id="home">
            <div id="app-status-div">
                <ul id="app-status-ul">
                    <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anything that i am missing or doing wrong?

EDIT: i added a few logs and determined that the onNotificationGCM() method is not getting called after the successHandler() is called

Comment: Same issue for me, cannot figure out, how to obtain a gcm register-ID/token

Comment: you'll have to test on a real device. does not work on an emulator. same code i tried on a real device and it worked like a charm

Comment: thanks, yes i did that .. the successHandler gets called - but only receives "OK" - the onNotificationGCM does not get called.

Comment: now it works - problem was: forgot to switch on "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" at google (Developers Console). *blush*

Comment: I have switched on the GCM for Android API and have my senderId correct and still only receiving "OK"

Comment: Hi, Can u please give solution for this answer . same problem for me and i m learning GCM in hybrid app. I m native developer . @user2739737

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the "ecb" handler supplied in the config object for `pushNotification.register` will get called with a "registered" event. The registration id will be supplied inside the object parameter supplied with the "ecb" handler. In the example this would be "ecb" = "onNotificationGCM".

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
  if(e.event == "registered") {
    alert(e.regid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that uses ngCordova with PushPlugin, when registering the device, the same callback to receive the notification reception has to be used to receive the regid. The regid comes in the same callback for event 'pushNotificationReceived' for android. Here is the code I use within the callback for that event to receive the regid:

Checking for (notification.event === 'registered') is the most important.

```
$rootScope.$on('pushNotificationReceived', function(event, notification) {

  //console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification));        

  console.log('Success: Inside the push notification received callback with this payload JSON' + notification);

  if(( platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android' ) && notification.regid && (notification.event === 'registered'))
  {
    var googDevToken = notification.regid;
    console.log(googDevToken);
  }

});
```